# How to set scroll position when using RecyclerView with FirestoreRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, uiscrollview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a `RecyclerView` to display some data from a Firestore database. I'm using as an adapter, the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` for obvious reasons. I'm successfully displaying all 35 items in my `RecyclerView`. The problem is, I cannot scroll to a specific position. This is what I have tried:

```
recyclerView = locationsFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

FirestoreRecyclerOptions<MyModelClass> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<MyModelClass>().setQuery(query, MyModelClass.class).build();
adapter = new MyFirestoreRecyclerAdapter(options);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(10);
```

Everytime I open my app, I'm always positioned at the first position and not on the 10'th as I specified in the `scrollToPosition()` method.

I have also used:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(10);
```

and

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(10);
```

But without luck. How do I scroll to specific position? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't scroll because you still don't have any items in the `recyclerView` when you call `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(10);`, you should use that code after the `recyclerView` gets populated from `Firebase`, probably inside a callback

Comment: @Signo Is the most reasonable explanation I have read on the internet so far. Thanks you but where should I move those lines of code, inside my adapter class or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `recyclerView` doesn't scroll because it's still empty when you call `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(10);`, you should move that code after the `recyclerView` gets populated from the `Firebase` response, probably inside a callback.

Comment: I solved the problem as you adviced me in your first comment. I have moved those lines of code inside the callback, after my `RecyclerView is populated. Please edit your answer so I can accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @IoanaP. Oh great, glad it worked! You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(10);` try to use below code to set position in recyclerview

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(10);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems like `smoothScrollToPosition()` method expects more then one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't want move to a specific position, instead I just wanted to keep the original position after returning from a different Activity or returning from background.

I just added this empty listener and it's working.

```
 listAdapter.snapshots.addChangeEventListener(object : ChangeEventListener {
        override fun onChildChanged(
            type: ChangeEventType,
            snapshot: DocumentSnapshot,
            newIndex: Int,
            oldIndex: Int
        ) {
        }

        override fun onDataChanged() {
        }

        override fun onError(e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
        }
    })
```

Here `listAdapter` is `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`.

Note: There must have some negative consequences on doing this.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved my problem with a Simpler solution.**

I just called `adapter.startListening();` in `onViewCreated()` instead of `onStart()` and called `adapter.stopListening();` in `onDestroyView()` instead of `onStop()`
That prevented the entire list from regenerating while coming back from the next activity and thus retained the scroll position where it was previously.

Source: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/998#issuecomment-342413662